# Unhandled exception in this simple Xamarin Android program

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm testing with my first Android Xamarin program in visual studio 2017, and have added a textview, with a switch to the main view. It builds fine, but when I click the switch I get an unhandled exception which gives no other details. Why is the exception being thrown, what is it and what am I doing wrong?

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace TestAndroidApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestAndroidApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }

        public void setActivatedLabel(View v)
        {
            var sw = (Switch)Resource.Id.switchActivate;
            ((TextView)Resource.Id.textActivated).Text = sw.Checked ? "On" : "Off";    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `FindViewById` to retrieve the object by the resource identifier:

```
var sw = FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.switchActivate);
var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textActivated);
textView.Text = sw.Checked ? "On" : "Off";
```

`sw` in this case will now be the `Switch` object that is referenced by the `switchActivate` id in your layout file that was loaded/inflated by the `SetContentView` method.

Comment: worked a treat! I also added an event handler in the `onCreate` for `checkedChanged`